Remap two-finger trackpad scrolling to right click hold plus scrolling for a video game
I am playing World of Warcraft on the trackpad, and there are two important actions:
a) Cursor movement: 1-finger movement.
b) Camera movement: 1-finger movement while holding right click.
It works surprisingly well on the trackpad but I want to simplify the second one by removing right click from there. What I want to achieve:
a) Cursor movement: 1-finger movement.
b) Camera movement: 2-fingers movement.
same as if it was a webpage in the browser:
a) Cursor movement: 1-finger movement.
b) Scrolling both directions: 2-fingers movement
In other words I want to remap two fingers trackpad scrolling to move cursor while holding right click or do something like hold right click when scrolling
